# Clean URLs with mod_rewrite and keep root path for includes (js and css)

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

**Setup:** I own a regular Unix Webserver running Apache and PHP.
It is serving PHP scripts as expected.

**Current Situation:** All my links look like typical PHP ones with parameters `website.net/index.php?show=article&do=new`

**What i want:** a mod_rewrite rule for remapping my urls, no matter how they look or contain.

**For example:** `website.net/article/new` should redirect to index.php and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` should contain `/article/new/` etc. but not limited to that and no fixed pattern (*n variables), all the other work is done with PHP (validating, including).

**My effort this far:** used google a lot and tried many expamples. but only found some with fixed patterns and some did even break the whole site.

**The other problem:** i noticed while experimenting with mod_rewrite that it broke the path to my js and css files.
I use relative pathes, they are located in a subfolder relative to index.php

`<script src="js/included_file.js"></script>`

`<link href="css/included_file.css" rel="stylesheet"">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-f` RewriteCondition to exclude files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f          #exclude files
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?__path=$1 [QSA]  #catch everything
```

If you want to keep directories too you can do that with `-d`.

Now if you call the URL:

```
website.net/path/to/file?query=string&foo=bar
```

You will get (in your `$_GET`):

```
__path = "/path/to/file"
query = "string"
foo = "bar"
```

---

Don't use `$_REQUEST`. It is non-standard and mixes `$_GET` and `$_POST`, it can lead to very strange bugs.

Comment: Sorry my fault, `$_REQUEST` should read `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.
The goal was to get rid of the `$_GET`. Will try your solution ASAP

Comment: There is no point in getting rid of `$_GET`, like `$_POST`, you _should_ use it. One thing you can do (and I recommend it) is: at the start of your script, mine all the input you need from `$_GET` and `$_SERVER` and never use these globals ever again. It's just good architecture design.

Comment: By getting rid, i mean more like "hide it from the users eye". I'm perfectly fine with using and accessing them like `$_GET["__path"]` from your solution. at the start of my script i indeed use a mechanism do validate and sanitize the input and storing them in a seperate array :)

Comment: You can opt not to use the QueryString. In that case you can leave off the `[QSA]` (QueryStringAppend) flag. This means you will _never_ see additional `$_GET` parameters, even if they are passed.

Comment: Tested your solution and it worked for the first folder hierarchy level. `website.net/articles/` works fine, but `website.net/atricles/new` will break the design because of missing css an js files. is there a way to fix this with mod_rewrite or should i use absolute URL to the files? i also excluded directories with -d

Comment: Oh, yea, don't use relative URLs. Change to `/js/included_file.js` and it should be fine.